# How to remove user and his /home contents

Tags: settings, user

If I remove a user at the relevant  user management settings, does it also destroy it's home directory contents? If not, what's the best way of eliminating that data and remove all the user footprint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty simple answer for this one. In order to the data be deleted with the removal of the user, one has to click on the delete user (small minus sign at the bottom of the user administration settings) instead of simply blocking the user.

That's it.

Comment: Done. Sorry for that Daniel.